# adapt windows and its content to screen size in java

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, screen

I have designed a java program that open in its main file a JFrame, where different panel are then opened. I found that using the program of different machine with different screen size it can be that some panel are "cut" and , for instance I loose some bottom in the panels.
What is the better designing solution to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance to who can help.

Comment: Perhaps toolkit? I Use that to get the exact size of the screen and make sure that none of my program needs to resized from the getgo. Take a look here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html  It's a really good tool for the multiplatform side of Java

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this sounds like a 'better' solution (btw. better than what?), but like  DreadHeadedDeveloper already said you can use toolkits.

Also, you can put everything on one panel and put that panel onto a scrollpane, which puts on scrollbars, if the screen is too small.

I dont know if you can make a final size or if you want to be able to resize it (which is often more trouble than it's worth).

What does: "where different panel are then opened" mean?
Should these panels be next to each other, or do they overlap? Do they change the size of your frame?

Answer (score 0):

Quite frankly, use QT or something like JavaFX, maybe Grails or anything but swing really but this is besides the point.

Anyway, for this you use LayoutManagers to reposition your elements for you. By using:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

you can get your screensize, after which you can give subpanels percentage based sizes. Say screenheight is 800, you can pass 800*0.40 if you want 40% of the parent height as the height for a child panel through the constructor of the panel.
Something like MyPanel extends Panel

```
public MyPanel(int width, int height){
  this.setSize(width,height);
}
```

The downside of layoutmanagers is that they can squish your components somewhat. I sincerely hope this at least helped you on your way to finding your answer!